# How to resize again on second click and not have more than one "open" at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to javascript (as in completely lost other than placing it in html and linking it to html) so I got a code from another question here to change the size of an image once clicked. The entire site is fluid so the width or each thumbnail goes from a fixed size to fill the width of the container which is a spry collapsible panel.

The problem is getting it to behave something like the collapsible in that it changes from 150px thumb to 100% full image and vice versa with each click but not having more than one image at 100% at the same time. Again, I'm completely new to this...

html for the image thumbnail:

```
<article class="thumb">
<h2>Test Image</h2>
<img id="img-gal" src="img/demopage/image-11.jpg"  style="width:150px; height:150px;" alt=""> </article>
```

script before body close

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumb').on('click', function(){
            $('#img-gal').css('width','100%');
            $('#img-gal').css('height','auto');
    });
});
</script>
```

[edit]

Here's the entire code... http://jsfiddle.net/AP7NW/

I took it over so I could be sure it wasn't a problem with other attributes. It now doesn't work T_T.

The action I want, in description would be something like:

*-out of several images in a gallery, user clicks an image thumbnail which happens to be the image at a fixed small size (image 11 for example)*

*-thumbnail expands to 100% width of page, moving the other thumbnails in their divs down in a sort of grid*

*-user clicks same image 11 and it reverts to thumbnail size*

*-user can click another image and it does the above but no two images are "open at the same time" i.e. the most recently clicked image is expanded to 100% and all other previous images clicked are at thumbnail size.*

I'm trying my best to avoid lightboxes, anything that has a tooltip or hover attribute and sliders. they usually don't do so well with smartphones like the s4 which i use for testing where swiping is almost a habit to go between pictures and cannot hover. A laptop on the other hand is quite natural to be clicking and hovering. The plugins that slide are never free, have problems with varying widths or collide with the css in the actual site they'll be used in.

Comment: need to see more html to know what is meant by `only one open`

Comment: I believe i understand what you're trying to do because I have it on my site (stole it from RedTeamDesign).  Check this out and see if it's what you're after - http://www.red-team-design.com/interactive-menu-with-css3-jquery

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumb').on('click', function(){
            $(this).css('width','100%');
            $(this).css('height','auto');
    });
});
</script>
```